# JL&U Hacks - Ruby Rendering

Tags: discussion, furigana

A brower script which render ruby (furigana) on-the-fly.

[image]

- Works on

  - Google Chrome (Tested only on Chrome 14 dev)
  - Firefox with GreaseMonkey (Tested only on Firefox 5.0, 7.0a1)
  - Opera (Tested only on Opera 11.50)
  - Safari with NinjaKit on Mac (Tested only on Safari 5.0 OSX 10.6.5)
  - Internet Explorer with Trixie (Tested only on IE8)
- Now work with live contents like added comments and dedicated support to `[]{}` format.
- Option to choose strictness level (ruby mode)

  [image]
- Option to hide ruby texts and convert those to hover texts
- Option to hide rōmaji ruby texts

Note: using localStorage to store settings

**For more info and download:**

- https://stackapps.com/questions/2449/hacks-for-jlu-site

**Note**: If you are not sure how to install userscript, please take a look at  https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info, and you may need to ***install*** again to get latest update.

More screen shots

[screenshot-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSaXA.png), [screenshot-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GeV6.png), [screenshot-4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZoR3.png)

Comment: Note: I have cleaned up all comments to get cleaner look.

Comment: Did the script get updated [when this change happened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372956/)? (...Did they actually change anything? It's not entirely clear to me from the discussion there...)

Comment: I am not sure about user script api supported by stack exchange, but user script in this post is merged into https://japanese.stackexchange.com/ since Geoff Dalgas answer, So, bacially api changes does not affect this I think.

Answer (score 9):

We have included this userscript as part of the core site to support rendering ruby (furigana) on-the-fly.  I will be watching this post for any updates to this script.  Thanks to YOU for his work on this thus far.

**EDIT:**
I have made additional edits to this script - the options will now be located in the footer:

[image: language options]

Comment: @YOU please download this version:  http://dev.sstatic.net/js/third-party/japanese-l-u.js and use this as a starting point for future updates.

Comment: Hi, I've added "em,strong" tag into parse list, supposed to be fixed [this](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/559/feature-bugfix-request-for-furigana) issue too. And created git repository for the update here - https://github.com/stackexchange-you/jlu