# How and where can someone use Ruby Text?

Tags: discussion, furigana

In my writings on the language, I often use the word(furigana) set up, and it works well most of the time. When it gets to be too much, or the word is like this(吹き上げ), it can become very problematic to keep up with. I know programs like Illustrator have functional workarounds and built in protocols(as this place seems to, from what I've seen around here), but for stuff like Word and blogging spots like Blogger and Wordpress, I have to resort to what I've been using all this time. Does anyone any insight they can share about using Ruby Text in those places?

Answer (score 1):

Ruby support wasn't originally available here, either - [Is it possible to add support for Ruby tags or any other mechanism for Furigana?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98/)

It's a matter of demand, and I think at the moment the demand isn't there for most Japanese sites (unless you're writing for kids or something). I think the assumption is that if people want furigana then they will use some add-on on their own browsers to supply it.

However, there are a few tools around, e.g. [this](http://htmldwarf.hanameiro.net/tools/ruby.html) which if html with ruby will work on the site you're writing on should be of use.

First box is just enter kanji, enter kana, return html for a single word.
Second box is, enter text, then for each word you want to add furigana to put the kanji and kana in the top box and hit 変換 to add html which will put furigana on the first occurrence of that word only.  (確認 shows you what it will look like).

Last box might be useful if you just want to type in your text and then convert all in once - you have to type a space before the word you want the furigana on, then ｜漢字《かんじ》 (for example).

For multiple words (looks actually like you don't need a space):
In last box, for example:
｜難《むずか》しい｜漢字《かんじ》にルビをふる

Or in second box, write text and then sequentially enter the kanji you want to add ruby to and then kana, then 変換 (e.g enter word one/kana one, press 変換, enter word two/kana two, press 変換).

Comment: Could you some me some examples with making the multiple word ruby texts?

Comment: Edited some in. I do think the ｜漢字《かんじ》method is easiest because you can type it directly in and then convert to html once.

Comment: What if the software doesn't want to make the Ruby Text stick? It works fine with Blogger, but when I went to Wordpress, it ends up stripping it out, leaving it looking like this(難《むずか》) after processing

Comment: Well, that's the choice of the website; often in blogging sites they limit how much html you can use (to avoid certain exploits/hacking), basically stripping any html tags out that aren't in their whitelist. Because not all browsers support <ruby> yet, it's really not that widely supported . There might be a way to get it to work, but you'd have to ask Wordpress directly.